# Why am I getting the error "EXC_BAD_ACCESS"

Tags: swift, xcode, autolayout

I am trying to debug my Autolayout using the suggestions of [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20180311113608/http://nshint.io/blog/2015/08/17/autolayout-breakpoints/) website, to highlight views that are causing constraint issues. However when I try to change the color of the suspect view with the command

```
expr ((UIView *)0x7f9ea3d43410).backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor]
```

I get the Error

```
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xcd4200020).
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.
```

I have also gotten the error:

```
error: Execution was interrupted, reason: Attempted to dereference an invalid ObjC Object or send it an unrecognized selector.
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.
```

I am not sure why I am getting this error as I have made sure to replace the example hex code with my own, what does this error even mean?

I am coding in swift, the website I reference uses objective-c, that may be my problem. what would the swift code be to do the same thing? I have tried:

```
expr ((UIView *)0x7f9ea3d43410).backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor
```

Comment: You are trying to cast a memory address to a variable of type "pointer to view" and then invoke a method on the object at that address. That is a very fragile way to set a property of a view. If you get the address wrong, all sorts of bad things will happen.  Instead of trying to set the views from the console to specific colors, why not set the colors of the views from your code?

Comment: Also note that the code you posted is Objective-C syntax, not Swift syntax. Are you debugging a Swift project? (Your question has the Swift tag, not the Objective-C tag.)

Comment: @DuncanC Yes, I am working in swift, as I mentioned in my question I cannot find a guide that uses swift code for my specific issue. The reason I am trying to change this view to a different color is that I am getting a broken constraint at that view and am trying to identify which view it is so that I can fix it.

Comment: That link is from 2015. I suspect it's too old to be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think the short answer is "that link is from 2015 and the recommended technique uses hidden internal symbols that are no longer supported."

Specifically, the symbol is _autoLayoutTrace. That is a private symbol which apparently has been dropped.

Comment: I am currently using the LLDB debugger so it is still supported.

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke about LLDB. It's GDB that was removed. The issue you're facing is that  the site you are using tells you to use a private symbol, `_autoLayoutTrace`, which is apparently no longer supported.